# How do you recompile a Flash project?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Firstly, thanks for your help. Here's my situation: I'm trying to edit the code for a flash mp3 player, specifically the xspf music player located here http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/  (I'm using the slim version). I downloaded the latest release and got a compressed file containing a .as file, a .fla file, and a .swf file. I've got the player working fine on my site, what I'd like to do is insert code to make an external javascript function call (as described here: [actionscript + javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757390/actionscript-javascript)) when the player loads a song. I've edited the .as file but that doesn't change anything, so I'm assuming I need to somehow re-compile. How do I do this? Also, I believe the actionscript is 2.0.

Thanks again. All comments are helpful as I'm lost with the amount of info available on flash, so many different version (flex, flex sdk, cs, etc, etc), and formats (.as, .fla, .swf)

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you're opening and editing the file using Flash, then what you need to do is go to File->Publish (something like that).

---

**Your other questions:**

Flex is for building Rich Internet Applications. It has your basic GUI controls and all that. It uses Actionscript MXML as its underlying languages.

Flash is more for creating animations and games. It does have some premade GUI components, but they don't look as traditional as Flex's.

The "CS" after Flash is "Creative Suite", which is part of Adobe's product line (with photoshop, dreamweaver, etc). The "CS" was added to it after Adobe bought Flash from Macromedia. If you see any versions of Flash without a CS after it (like flash MX), it is a very old version.

---

**Your questions about file formats:**

.as is a file that contains
   Actionscript. This is the programming
   language used in Flex and Flash.

.fla is a raw movie project file. This contains all of your graphical assets, as well as .as files and others.

.swf is a compiled movie. This is what a .fla turns into when you do the step I told you to do. This is what you download when you watch a flash video online.

Comment: So would you recommend I d/l and use flex? Is this what you mean when you say, "if you're opening and editing the file using Flash", is flex the "flash"? That's one of my main confusions...

Comment: If you're merely editing an application, it really depends on what it was made in. Chances are it was made in Flash, so you should use that if you want. I'm assuming you know what you can do with Flash, so just to illustrate the difference between that and Flex, here is an application made in Flex: http://www.volkswagen.co.uk/used/search See how it's "business like"? It has a regular GUI, just like every other desktop app. Keep in mind - anything you can do in Flex you can do in Flash, and vice versa. But depending on your application, one may be easier than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Open the fla-file in Flash and select Publish from the File menu. This will compile the fla- and as-files into a swf-file containing your changes.